# networkx: remove edge with specific attribute from multigraph

Tags: networkx

I'd like to remove a specific edge (specific color) from a MultiGraph.

How can I do that?

Following code does not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiGraph()
# the_colored_graph.add_edge(v1, v2, "red")
G.add_edge(1, 2, color="red")
G.add_edge(2, 3, color="red")
G.add_edge(4, 2, color="green")
G.add_edge(2, 4, color="blue")

print (G.edges(data=True))

# G.remove_edge(2, 4, color="green")
#
selected_edge = [(u,v) for u,v,e in G.edges(data=True) if e['color'] == 'green']
print (selected_edge)
G.remove_edge(selected_edge[0][0], selected_edge[0][1])

print (G.edges(data=True))

nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried you code, its working. Can you post the output you are recieving ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing the multigraph, assign a "key" attribute to each edge (the key could be anything that disambiguates the parallel edges - say, the color):

```
G.add_edge(1, 2, color="red", key='red')
```

Remove an edges by specifying the end nodes and the key:

```
G.remove_edge(1, 2, key='red')
```

Comment: Does it have to be unique among the entire graph or only for the multiple edges of two specific nodes?

Comment: Thanks. I also saw that even if you don't set a specific key, networkx gives a unique (for each edge) key automatically.

Comment: But you woudn't know which key to use unless you assigned it yourself, would you?

Comment: You are right. I may search for the key that has that color, but it is much simplyer your way. This is what you have if you don't assign a key ({0: {'color': 'green'}, 1: {'color': 'blue'}})

Comment: As a matter of facts I will directly use key instead of color: G.add_edge(1, 2, key="blue")